# How can I find out from subversion who made the original commit on a file?

Tags: svn, commit

I need a solution for Windows to the question "how can I find out from subversion who made the original commit on a file?"

I have python available.

The question really is "what is the best thing to ask subversion, to get this most easily".   I can see that svn log of a file has the original author between two `|` towards the end of the output, but this is pretty cumbersome.   Is there an svn commmand to get closer to the answer before processing?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "original"? The very first commit when the file was added/imported to repository?

Comment: Yes exactly that.  The person who make the first ("original") commit.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the **--xml** option in your log command and load/parse the resulting XML.
The resulting format (nonverbose) looks like this:

```
<log>
  <logentry revision="54321">
    <author>PeterParker</author>
    <date>2016-01-07T08:03:07.170482Z</date>
    <msg>Here is the log message</msg>
  </logentry>
  <logentry revision="54320">
    [...]
  </logentry>
</log>
```